# Derivative of derivative squared with respect to same variable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

What is the answer, and how should I go forth do derivate something like this.
$$\frac d{dx}((\frac {dy}{dx})^2)$$

Comment: *Hint:* Try writing $\displaystyle u = \frac{dy}{dx}$. Then apply the chain rule to 
$$\frac{d\ }{dx} u^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=\frac{dy}{dx}$. 
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 = \frac{d g^2}{dx} = 2 g\frac{dg}{dx} = 2 \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} $$